# Mapping array of union type in object

Tags: typescript

I have the following example that I'd like to make it work. See comments in code:

```js
const cars = {
    "audi": {
        manufacturer: "audi",
        colors: ["red", "blue"]
    },
    "mercedes": {
        manufacturer: "mercedes",
        colors: ["blue", "black"]
    }
} as const

type CarType = typeof cars[keyof typeof cars]

type Mapper<C extends CarType> = {
    manufacturer: C["manufacturer"]
    color: C["colors"][number]
}

type Car = Mapper<CarType>

const car: Car = {
    manufacturer: "audi",
    color: "black" // <- this is wrong, only "red" and "blue" are valid
}
```

As it can be seen from the example, I would like to have a `color` field that has only a single option and is derived from the list of valid `colors`.

The issue is that my `Mapper` type is wrong, because it does not pick out individual `CarType`s, but I don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stand-alone type that achieves this would look like this:

```
type Car = {
  [K in keyof typeof cars]: {
    manufacturer: typeof cars[K]["manufacturer"],
    colors: typeof cars[K]["colors"][number]
  }
}[keyof typeof cars]
```

You can map over the `cars` to create a valid object for each key of `cars`. With `[keyof typeof cars]` we can index this type to get a union of all possible car types.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noStrictGenericChecks=true&esModuleInterop=false&experimentalDecorators=false&emitDecoratorMetadata=false&target=6&jsx=0&module=1&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=false&noImplicitOverride=true&ts=4.4.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCGAnCMC8MDeBYAUDfMARPAK4AmAloQFya4EMwC28YJAZvMFCYgKaJaxclQA09RvlAAbEMloBtQvzKFRRAEbSSfQgF0J%20AL7i8BQkwHA%20ZPhBp0zklm07deAoZcTXb905JSILLyMEpaOmqa0lwA1vqGMEa4RjDwKKCQULi4UACeAA58MADCSGiO%20AoA0jAUYDCxfHkg7DD5Ra1wSBB6tNhOzKwcXDz8gu2FfF0IyDV6Si4j7uP6AQQychC0HdNtsxDzSpvI%20gpsTBoCBmbJOEYKTS1tuzM9N7iZ0N0TZYgVAwYSzcY08RFIlDUiROQi0cUIMAA9IiYAAeAC07QAFhQULiYAB3RDgADm6nA0jyRBUCNYZGikTS-BgADd4NIKGQUkA)

---

A more generic solution:

```
type Mapper<T extends Record<string, { manufacturer: string, colors: readonly string[] }>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    manufacturer: T[K]["manufacturer"],
    colors: T[K]["colors"][number]
  }
}[keyof T]

const car: Mapper<typeof cars> = {
    manufacturer: "audi",
    color: "black" // <- this is wrong, only "red" and "blue" are valid
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks great. Will test it later and accept it soon.